# Matlab multiply with a negativ number shows me 0

Tags: matlab, dct

Im trying to read the rgb's of an image and multiply them with -1. The problem is that every Output of this script is 0. A(1,1) for example is 144 and 144 * -1 isnt 0. So what am i missing here?

```
A = imread('image.ppm');
[M,N] = size(A);
blocksize = 8;

for i=1:1:blocksize
   for j=1:1:blocksize
         disp(A(i,j) * - 1);
   end
end
```

Comment: Pixel value can't be negative in `uint8` type.

Comment: Is it possible to copy the value of the Pixel to an int?

Comment: Yes, `a=double(uint8_number)`. I think @Cris wrote a better way which is `A=im2double(A)` it will convert all pixels into double type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`A` is of type `uint8`. MATLAB uses saturated arithmetic with integers. In saturated arithmetic, `144 * -1 = -144 = 0`.

The solution is to use [`im2double`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/im2double.html):

```
A=im2double(A)
```

Note that MATLAB keeps images of class `double` in the range [0,1], and of class `uint8` in the range [0,255]. You will notice this difference when using `imshow` and `imsave`. `im2double` will convert the ranges properly.